Reading Json file and calling a post api with each email and token
I have a outpout.json file which contains email and token as a key value pair and i want to call a post api for each of these email in a shell script but it is calling the api only once for the first email and token not the next one
{
    "md.arbaaz@deeplogictech.com":"9RN_5atv9F1e0zCKrkjRHQP1IYu1Wknz",
    "ajay.bhatheja@deeplogictech.com":"2Is864BMgiocY0gveVZZSelB4YT5fP-G"
}

this is my shell script
#!/bin/bash

send_email() {
    local email=$1
    local token=$2

    echo "Sending email to: $email, Token: $token"  # Add logging
    # Call API using curl with request body only
    response=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"email\": \"$email\", \"token\": \"$token\"}" http://127.0.0.1:8081/emailIssues)
    echo "API Response: $response"  # Log API response
}

# Check if output.json exists in the same directory
if [ ! -f "output.json" ]; then
    echo "Error: output.json file not found"
    exit 1
fi

# Read and process JSON data
json=$(cat output.json)
echo "JSON Data: $json"  # Log JSON data
echo "$json" | jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.value) \(.key)"' | while read -r token email; do
    echo "Processing: Email: $email, Token: $token"  # Log processing of each email and token
    # Call send_email function with email and token
    send_email "$email" "$token"
done


i was expecting that for each email and token  it will call the api

Try: while read -r token email; do ... ;done < <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.value) \(.key)"' <output.json)

Does this answer your question? Why piping input to "read" only works when fed into "while read ..." construct?
or this: How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?

Consider changing jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.value) \(.key)"' to jq -c 'to_entries[] | {email: .key, token: .value}', and then just read by line. Each will be a JSON-encoded string that you can directly pass into curl -d (without having to manually recompose the JSON encoding).
